# ci rest server allow CORS doesn't works

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter, cors

Hay guys I have tasks from college to make elearning rest server, when i deployed it to VPS  so it's getting an error that said:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://IP_VPS/elearning/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

i'm using chriskacerguis ci library and the controller is ***AUTH.php*** extends to ***Token.php*** extends to ***REST_Controller.php***.

application/controller/api/Token.php

```
<?php
// load library rest server
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

// load library rest server
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
require APPPATH . 'libraries/JWT.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/BeforeValidException.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/ExpiredException.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/SignatureInvalidException.php';

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Token extends REST_Controller {

  private $_secretkey = 'elearning';
  private $_token;

  public function __construct(){
    // ALLOW CORS
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
        exit;
    }
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_users', 'user');
  }

  public function getToken() {
    return $this->_token;
  }

  public function generateToken($user){
  }

  public function authToken($admin_access = null){
  }

  public function decodeToken($token) {
  }
}

?>
```

in ***application/controllers/Auth.php*** i didn't put header CORS to the constructor bcoz i already put it before but still doesn't works.

client (i upload it to github.io)

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://IP_VPS/elearning/auth/login');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.response);
    }
  }
  xhr.send('email='+email.value+'&password='+password.value);
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Con$
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Con$
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Con$
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

# codeigniter elearning
# i created it by myself
location /elearning {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /elearning/index.php;
}
```

Is there any wrong with my controllers/configuration ? im super new at build rest server and deploy it. Im sorry if this question too stupid im actually so confused what should i do right now. I hope my question will not be closed. Thanks anyway guys